# Testing for an event value

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, sinon

I'm working on an AngularJS project. The UI is a HTML file but the functions are held in js viewmodel file. I am trying to write a spec to check for a value in an event property.
But I get the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectionStart' of undefined

```
function onKeyPress(event){
   if(event.key === 'Enter') {
      // do stuff
   } else {
      _selectionStart = event.target.selectionStart;
   }    
}

it('should have a value in selectionStart', function(){
   viewModel.selectionStart = 0; 
   viewModel.onKeyPress({key:'X'});
});
```

Comment: it seems like your `event.target` is undefined. You can `console.log(event)` to see what event contains...  I might have thought that the target is the input box... also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event and see what happens with `keyup`

Comment: Add `target` property to `event`. Call the `function` like this `viewModel.onKeyPress({key:'X', target: {selectionStart:''}});`

Comment: oh... these are mocked up values inside of Jasmine?

Comment: nopole and @aditya-bhave you have both helped tremendously.
I understand now that I was accessing/setting 'target' incorrectly.